# How do I iterate over functions that return rxjs observables

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to iterate over a series of asynchronous functions and end the iterating when a false is returned.
I'm new to `rxjs` and can't get the use-case below to work. I feel like I'm not understanding something fundamental. Can someone please point it out to me?

```
function validateA(): Observable<any> {
  // do stuff.
  return of({ id: "A", result: true }); // hardcoding result for now
}

function validateB(): Observable<any> {
  // do stuff
  return of({ id: "B", result: true }); // hardcoding result for now
}

function validateC(): Observable<any> {
  // do stuff
  return of({ id: "C", result: false });// hardcoding result for now
}

from([validateA, validateB, validateC])
  .pipe(
    map(data => data()),
    takeWhile(data => !!data.result)
  )
  .subscribe(data => console.log(`${data.id} passed!`));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ub9c5r?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the core of your logic is right. What is missing is some rxJs pecularity.

The solutions could be something like this. Explanation of the nuances are in the comments.

```
// start from an array of functions and turn it into a stream using RxJs from function
from([validateA, validateB, validateC])
  .pipe(
    // now execute each function sequentially, one after the other, via concatMap
    // operator. This operator calls each function and each function returns an Observable
    // concatMap ensures that the functions are called sequentially and also that the returned Observable (because each function returns an Observable)
    // is "flattened" in the result stream. In other words, you execute each function one at the time
    // and return the value emitted by the Observable returned by that function
    // until that Observable completes. Considering that you use the "of" function to
    // create the Observable which is returned by each function, such Observable emits just one value and then completes.
    concatMap(func => func()),
    // now you have a stream of values notified by the Observables returned by the functions
    // and you terminate as soon as a flase is received
    takeWhile(data => !!data.result)
  )
  .subscribe(data => console.log(`${data.id} passed!`));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the trick and calls functions lazily:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-9ystxv?file=index.ts

```
import {  from, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import {  concatAll, find, map } from "rxjs/operators";

function validateA() {
  console.log('validateA');
  return of({ id: "A", result: false });
}

function validateB() {
  console.log('validateB');
  return of({ id: "B", result: true });
}

function validateC() {
  console.log('validateC');
  return of({ id: "C", result: false });
}

from([validateA, validateB, validateC])
  .pipe(
    map(validate => validate()),
    concatAll(),
    find(data => data.result)
  )
  .subscribe(data => console.log(`${data.id} passed!`));
```